# Funcion de firebase no funciona

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estoy implementando los siguientes enlaces de Firebase en mi HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-app.js"></script>´
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom/crudBeneficiarios.js"></script>
```

Archivo crudBeneficiarios.js:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "miApiKey",
authDomain: "miAuthDomain",
databaseURL: "miURL",
projectId: "miProjectID",
storageBucket: "miStorageBucket",
messagingSenderId: "miMessagingSenderId",
appId: "miAppID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Pero la siguiente linea me causa conflicto:

```
var db = firebase.database();
```

Lo hago tal y como aparece en la documentación de firebase, no se que esta mal.
El error que me aparece es:

> firebase.database is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita el `defer` a los scripts. `defer` hace que el script se ejecute hasta que la página ha sido renderizada, entonces los scripts con defer se pausan pero luego se ejecuta el script de `crudBeneficiarios.js` y eso causa el error.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```